# Styling Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I am working on a dataframe **df**. I am trying to set the background color of the cells of the **'SupTrend'** column. The background should be red when the value in **'Price'** column is lower than the value in **'SupTrend'** column, and it should be green otherwise. I tried everything, checked the documentation and I can't find any explanation or solution for my problem. It seems data inside the function is converted to string and I guess I can't convert it to float. Does someone knows how to solve this?

```
    def highlight_suptrend(x, data):
           return f"background-color: red;" if data['Price'].all() < data['SupTrend'].all() else f"background-color: green;"
    
    df.style.applymap(highlight_suptrend, data=df[['Price', 'SupTrend']], subset=['SupTrend'])
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`style.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) rather than [`style.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap), and then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for your function `return`, selecting `red` where `Price` is lower than `SupTrend` and `green` otherwise (using: [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html)).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some mock data
np.random.seed(1)

data = {'Price': np.random.randint(1,11,10),
        'SupTrend': np.random.randint(1,11,10)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def highlight_suptrend(x, data):
    return np.where(data['Price'].lt(data['SupTrend']), 
                    "background-color: red", 
                    "background-color: green")

df.style.apply(highlight_suptrend, 
               data=df[['Price', 'SupTrend']], 
               subset=['SupTrend'])
```

Result:

[image: result]